# Multiple left joins and performance

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

**products - 4500 records**

Fields: id, sku, name, alias, price, special_price, quantity, desc, photo, manufacturer_id, model_id, hits, publishing

**products_attribute_rel - 35000 records**

Fields: id, product_id, attribute_id, attribute_val_id

**attribute_values - 243 records**

Fields: id, attr_id, value, ordering

**manufacturers - 29 records**

Fields: id, title,publishing

**models -  946 records**

Fields: id, manufacturer_id, title, publishing

So I get data from these tables by one query:

```
SELECT jp.*,
       jm.id AS jm_id,
       jm.title AS jm_title,
       jmo.id AS jmo_id,
       jmo.title AS jmo_title
FROM `products` AS jp 
LEFT JOIN `products_attribute_rel` AS jpar ON jpar.product_id = jp.id
LEFT JOIN `attribute_values` AS jav ON jav.attr_id = jpar.attribute_val_id
LEFT JOIN `manufacturers` AS jm ON jm.id = jp.manufacturer_id
LEFT JOIN `models` AS jmo ON jmo.id = jp.model_id 
GROUP BY jp.id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT jpar.attribute_val_id) >= 0
```

This query is slow as hell. It takes hundreds of seconds mysql to handle it.
So how it would be possible to improve this query ? With small data chunks it works 
perfectly well. But I guess everything ruins `products_attribute_rel` table, which
has 35000 records.

Your help would be appreciated.

**EDITED**

`EXPLAIN` results of the `SELECT` query:

[image: EXPLAIN results of the SELECT query]

Comment: You may need to create non-cluster covering indexes.

Comment: Do you use any indexation method like b-tree and so ?

Comment: put `EXPLAIN` in front of `SELECT` and show us the result. That may help us finding out what the bottlenecks are.

Comment: I've edited my post. So now you can see the EXPLAIN query results in the screenshot.

Comment: The disaster is not the (small) table with 35K rows. It's that you have no indexes (except the PRIMARY KEYs) on 3 of the 5 tables. Add an index on every column that is used for Joining.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that MySQL uses the join-type `ALL` for 3 tables. That means that MySQL performs 3 full table scans, puts every possibility together before sorting those out that don't match the `ON` statement. To get a much faster join-type (for instance `eq_ref`), you must put an index on the coloumns that are used on the `ON` statements.

Be aware though that putting an index on every possible coloumn is not recommended. A lot of indexes do speed up `SELECT` statements, however it also creates an overhead since the index must be stored and managed. This means that manipulation queries like `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are much slower. I've seen queries deleting only 1000 records in half an hour. It's a trade-off where you have to decide what happens more often and what is more important.

To get more infos on MySQL join-types, take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types).
More on indexes [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: Thanks Mike. I put indexes and now everything works just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Tables data is not so much huge that it's taking hundreds of seconds. Something is wrong with table schema. Please do proper indexing. That will surly speed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct
jm.id AS jm_id,
jm.title AS jm_title,
jmo.id AS jmo_id,
jmo.title AS jmo_title
from products jp, 
products_attribute_rel jpar,
attribute_values jav,
manufacturers jm
models jmo
where jpar.product_id = jp.id
and jav.attr_id = jpar.attribute_val_id
and jm.id = jp.manufacturer_id
and jmo.id = jp.model_id
```

you can do that if you want to select all the data. Hope it works.